# See if an JSON array in MySQL contains an object whose key holds a specific date

Tags: mysql, json

i'm trying to find out if there is a row which contains a specific date inside a JSON array

Let's say my data looks like this:

#### Table applications:

```
id | application_id | data
```

```
# Rows
1 | 1 | [{"data" : ["some", "data#1"], "date": "2016-04-21"}, {"data" : ["other", "data#1"], "date" : "2016-04-22"}]
2 | 2 | [{"data" : ["some", "data#2"], "date": "2016-04-21"}, {"data" : ["other", "data#2"], "date" : "2016-04-26"}]
3 | 1 | [{"data" : ["some", "data#3"], "date": "2016-04-22"}, {"data" : ["other", "data#3"], "date" : "2016-04-26"}]
4 | 3 | [{"data" : ["some", "data#4"], "date": "2016-04-26"}]
```

How can I find all the applications whose data contains the date `'2016-04-26'`?

So basically I can do this:

```
select id, json_extract(`data`, "$[*].date") from applications
```

Which returns:

```
1 | ["2016-04-21", "2016-04-22"]
2 | ["2016-04-21", "2016-04-26"]
3 | ["2016-04-22", "2016-04-26"]
4 | ["2016-04-26"]
```

But if try to use `json_extract` in the `WHERE` clause I can only use it if I explicitly tell the array's key in the `json_extract`'s path argument, like so:

```
select * from applications where json_extract(`data`, "$[0].date") = "2016-04-26"
```

which correctly returns the row with id 4.

But if I try to use a wildcard in the path then it no longer works:

```
select * from applications where json_extract(`data`, "$[*].date") = "2016-04-26"
```

this should return the rows 2, 3, 4.

I tried many other options/variations but I can't seem to find a way to structure the query correctly.

Is something like this even possible with the current implementation of MySQL JSON?

Answer (score 23):

One solution as provided by Morgan Tucker - @morgo is to use `json_contains` like so:

```
select * from applications where json_contains(`data`, '{"date" : "2016-04-26"}')
```

For now the answer is OK, but i believe it can have some performance issues and feels a bit hackish to me (see the next query) - but I will deal with those when i get there :)

If I would need to query on a date range (from `2016-04-24` to `2016-04-26`) I would need to add an invididual `json_contains` for each day in the time span like so:

```
select * from applications where json_contains(`data`, '{"date" : "2016-04-26"}') or json_contains(`data`, '{"date" : "2016-04-25"}') or json_contains(`data`, '{"date" : "2016-04-24"}')
```

And this would return invalid data if I would have an `date` key nested somewhere else

So if you have an different solution, I would like to know

Comment: as variant - define max depth of date array - SELECT MAX(json_depth(data ->> '$[*].date')), than thru the loop in stored procedure extract to temp tables - id and selected date - select id, json_extract(`data`, "$[0].date") as 'date' from applications, than-  select id, json_extract(`data`, "$[1].date") as 'date' from applications, and etc.  than apply all filter and have list of id

Comment: you gave me a clue on how to use the json_contains syntax